# Font-face using ttf remotely

Tags: html, css, truetype

I have a bit of code that I'm using to create barcodes using a Code39r.ttf font.

When using it on my local machine it seems to work fine

```
<html>

<head>

<style>

@font-face {
   font-family:code;
   src: url(Code39r.ttf);
}

#myFont {
   color:#111111;
   font-size:180px;
   font-family:code;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

    <p id="myFont">123 456</p>

</body>
</html>
```

As soon as I try to load the font from an online source it never seems to load

https://jsfiddle.net/jhc7p69p/2/

not sure what could have gone wrong or if there is a reason for this

Comment: If it is working fine on your local machine, then it might be where you have the font file located on the server. clearly the CSS is not finding it

Comment: if I copy the usrl used in the JFiddle though into the browser it downloads the font so what could cause it not to be found

Comment: here is a good place to look: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Answer (score 1):

you use custom font you require more font file like.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

body {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont', Fallback, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: This won't help because I only have a ttf file

Comment: other file generator to online

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Ok I used the fontsquirrel to create the new font types woff and woff2 and loaded them to my server and updated my JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jhc7p69p/2/ it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Blocked loading mixed active content "http://shoepack.com/resources/code39azalea.woff"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121728/discussion-between-lalji-tadhani-and-trent).